# Is it possible to put both image and text in Segmentcontrol?

Tags: ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing an iPad app. I want to show a UISegmentedControl with both image and text in each segment. Is it possible to do so?. Please clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614284/uisegmentedcontrol-text-with-multiple-lines) for a Two-Line-SegmentControl. Just put UIImageViews instead of additional UILabels in the segments.

Comment: the code you pointed out just takes in multiline text inside single label. Where should we add UIImageViews in your code? Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: The code placed own views into the segments view hierarchy before. It was changed to use just images now. A solution to your problem would be a UIView with an UILabel and an UIImageView. Render its layer into an image context and use that image in your segment.