# UISegmentedControl text with multiple lines?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I make the text in one of the buttons in my UISegmentedControl span multiple lines?

Answer (score 44):

Use UIAppearance to get things done. The below code snippet will work. Call this before creating your segment.

**Objective-C**

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] setNumberOfLines:0];
```

**Swift**

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: Since someone downvoted: It shouldn't work (numberOfLines isn't even a UIAppearance selector), but it actually works. Proof: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gE7Dv.png Problem seems to be that the label width seems to be taken solely from the first line. That's why I added these spaces in the code.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch try removing the new line character

Comment: Without the newline it wouldn't be a multi line label. ;) Thanks anyway, but I don't have that problem anymore, I solved it with the top-voted answer a while ago. Just wanted to explain that the downvote was not necessary.

Comment: This API is available on iOS 9.0+.

Comment: [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISegmentedControl class]]] setNumberOfLines:0];
this code will work for iOS 12

Comment: Swift 5 (add in AppDelegate to get this to work for controls added in Storyboard): UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score 32):

I did it this way:

- create a multiline UILabel
- fill the label with N lines of text
- convert the label into an UIImage
- set the image as a segments content

This works smooth on iOS 4, 5, 6

[image: Sample Image iOS 5]

and iOS 7 (just remove the text shadow)

[image: Sample Image iOS 7]

*MultiLineSegmentedControl - header file*

```
//
//  MultiLineSegmentedControl.h
//
//  Created by Jens Kreiensiek on 20.07.11.
//  Copyright 2011 SoButz. All rights reserved.
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MultiLineSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
- (void)setMultilineTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;
@end
```

*MultiLineSegmentedControl - implementation file*

```
//
//  MultiLineSegmentedControl.m
//
//  Created by Jens Kreiensiek on 20.07.11.
//  Copyright 2011 SoButz. All rights reserved.
//
#import "MultiLineSegmentedControl.h"
#import "UIView+LayerShot.h"

@interface MultiLineSegmentedControl()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *theLabel;
@end

@implementation MultiLineSegmentedControl
@synthesize theLabel;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.theLabel = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


- (UILabel *)theLabel
{
    if (!self->theLabel) {

        self->theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self->theLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self->theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self->theLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        self->theLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        self->theLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        self->theLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self->theLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }

    return self->theLabel;
}


- (void)setMultilineTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
{
    self.theLabel.text = title;
    [self.theLabel sizeToFit];

    [self setImage:self.theLabel.imageFromLayer forSegmentAtIndex:segment];
}

@end
```

*UIView+LayerShot - header file*

```
//
//  UIView+LayerShot.h
//
//  Created by Jens Kreiensiek on 29.06.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 SoButz. All rights reserved.
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (LayerShot)
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer;
@end
```

*UIView+LayerShot - implementation file*

```
//
//  UIView+LayerShot.m
//
//  Created by Jens Kreiensiek on 29.06.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 SoButz. All rights reserved.
//
#import "UIView+LayerShot.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (LayerShot)

- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

@end
```

Use it just like a normal UISegmentedControl:

```
...

MultiLineSegmentedControl *segment = [[MultiLineSegmentedControl alloc] 
    initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil]];

segment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, segment.frame.size.height * 1.5);

[segment setMultilineTitle:@"Title A\nSubtitle A" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segment setMultilineTitle:@"Title B\nSubtitle B" forSegmentAtIndex:1];

[self.view addSubview:segment];
[segment release];

...
```

Comment: @SoButz: I can't see any subtitle. I created subclass of UISegmentedControl & added above code. Create a MultiLineSegmentedControl in viewDidLoad of my view controller. But its not showing subtitle. I have #import "MultiLineSegmentedControl.h". Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: iOSAppDev, I have updated the example to the method I'm using now on iOS 6. Give it a try...

Comment: @SoButz: I have Segment names as @"All", @"My\nFriends",@"Closing\nSoon", @"Nearby". But still its not showing correctly. [Have a look](http://s8.postimage.org/hb724i105/SEGMENTED.png) Whats going wrong here ?

Comment: m also having the same problem as specified by @iOSAppDev

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3+** syntax based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30410759/3659227) by @Saranya Sivanandham

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: it is not working for me :( did anyone try this and had the expected result ??

Comment: @Venkatesh Chejaria. Yes, adding this line in your App Delegate or any other class would work for UISegmentedControl that's added either programmatically or from Storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

The approach above is better, but for the sake of having an alternative, you can do something like:

```
for(UIView *subview in segmentedControl.subviews) {
        if([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) isEqualToString:@"UISegment"]) {
            for(UIView *segmentSubview in subview.subviews) {
                if([NSStringFromClass(segmentSubview.class) isEqualToString:@"UISegmentLabel"]) {
                    UILabel *label = (id)segmentSubview;
                    label.numberOfLines = 2;
                    label.text = @"Hello\nWorld";
                    CGRect frame = label.frame;
                    frame.size = label.superview.frame.size;
                    label.frame = frame;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @moby, thanks for your alternative.
if I want to give a different name for my label text, how can I do it in your alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Years later...

```
     for segment in segmented.subviews{
        for label in segment.subviews{
            if let labels = label as? UILabel{
                labels.numberOfLines = 2

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not working no more

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS 12**, the below code will work like charm

```
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISegmentedControl class]]] setNumberOfLines:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a storyboard with UISegmentedControl in some views. I drag those controls to my class as `@IBOutlet`. Here are some codes to make labels in segmented controls multiple lines:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  ...
  @IBOutlet weak var segmentedCtrl: UISegmentedControl!
  {
     didSet {
       // localize strings
       let text1 = ... // localizedString
       ...
       segmentedCtrl.setTitle(text1, forSegmentAt: 0)
       ...
       // Following code making multiple lines happen!
       UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:     
         [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
     }
     ...
  }
```