# UISegmentedControl and localized strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with 3 segments. The English strings fit perfectly, but Spanish strings are slightly longer and don't.

[image]

[image]

What is the correct procedure to manipulate font size dynamically for the string to fit the size of the segment? Is there something similar to the `minimumFontScale` property for `UILabel`?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028619/is-it-possible-to-create-multi-line-uisegmentedcontrol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one
You didn't need to set any min font size. It will change font size automatically to show title if needed.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Title1 testing font size", @"Title2", @"Titl3",nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = YOUR_FRAME;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentControlClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    for (id segment in [segmentedControl subviews])
    {
        for (id label in [segment subviews])
        {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
[_segmentedControl.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *lblCaption = (UILabel *)obj;
            lblCaption.minimumFontSize=10.0f;
//OR
            lblCaption.minimumFontSize = 0.5f;
        }
    }];     
}];
```

Comment: for iOS6 change 'minimumFontSize' to --> "lblCaption.minimumScaleFactor=.5f"

Comment: @mtb Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated answer accordingly.